# Endless loop when threading with timer class

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I've created a timer class and am testing it with junit4. The timer is notifies another class of the time which then activates a method. While testing I am unable to check what values are sent to the observer because the compiler gets stuck in the always loop used for the timer. Here's the test and the start code for the timer.

```
 public void testSimpleTimerAsThread() throws InterruptedException 
    { 
     SimpleTimer st = new SimpleTimer(1000); 
     st.start(); 
     Thread.sleep(250); // So we are 1/4th a second different 
     for (int x=0;x<5;x++) 
     { 
     assertEquals(x, st.getRound()); // assumes round starts at
     Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for the next time change
     } 
    }

public void start()
    {
        while (flag)
        {
            timeChanged();
            try
            {
                // Sleep for var seconds.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show the entire definition of `SimpleTimer`. What does it extend and/or implement?  You haven't posted enough of the important details of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SimpleTimer` class you should be overriding the `run()` method, not `start()`.

Assuming `SimpleTimer` extends `Thread`, you have overridden the method in `Thread` that actually creates and launches the thread, so no new thread is being created and your thread code is being executed in the main thread when you invoke `start()`, which is why it hangs.